# Resharper 4.5 Intellisense: Is there anything better?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

Does anyone know if i can use another intellisense "helper" with resharper? I'm looking for suggestions of intellisense plugins to replace resharper's or ways to improve resharper intellisense..

I dont know if its just me, but Resharper's intellisense just seems way worst than visual studio's intellisense.

Comment: Could you describe what's wrong with VS or Resharper's IntelliSense ?

Comment: VS intellisense is fine, I mean, it's not that smart but it does it's job by saving some time with autocomplete and stuff. But Resarhper's intellisense does absolutely nothing. I dont know if it's just me, but I tought that it should at least be an improvment over VS intellisense, but to be honest all it does is remove some features from VS intellisense and replace it with an uglier UI.

Comment: maybe your installation of Resharper is broken? I've been using Resharper 4.5 and now 5.0 and it's far better then VS.

Answer (score 3):

I love Resharper 5 '**contains**' mode intellisense!
(I've migrated from Prod to it's Beta version even only for this feature!)

Thanks that you don't need to know exact name of method, type etc.
Eg when I'd like to use method with 'exit' in  can just type few letters and see as below:

[Contains search method http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3158/screen037.gif](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3158/screen037.gif)

Biggest pain is noticeable slow down of environment. But I can pay this price...

Answer (score 1):

Try ReSharper 5

Comment: both visual studio 2010 and resharper 5 are not yet ready for use in work environments.

when the tool is mature enough, i will upgrade from 4.5 to 5.0, but until then...

Comment: Do you consider it mature enough today, when it is released?

Comment: I've been burned by the installer for nightly builds.  My VS main hive is corrupted such that "devenv /setup" segfaults, and uninstalling the nightly build followed by installing a beta or release never repaired the issue.  Going to have to re-image my box if I can't find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Resharper with VS intellisense.

Comment: Yes I know, it's what I'm currently using. Bu I assume there must be a plugin or something that can give me a better intellisense, and that's what I'm asking suggestions for.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing I find that I lost with resharper (7 right now) was that VS intellisense would remember your last/frequent selections, alot of coding revolved around just hitting dot key alot for most ocmmon sequences. I find im alot slower with resharper's.